# logic for score based on 'yes' 'no' questions answered in a quiz

Tags: php

Please tell me the logic for calculating a score based on yes no clicks.
There are $n$ questions. For each question there are yes no buttons available. 
The logic should be in such a way that on clicking a yes button  +5 marks should be added to the score.
Similarly on clicking a no button -3 marks should be subtracted from the score.
After all the questions are completed I should get the total score for all the $n$ questions.

Comment: What have you got so far? Anything?

Comment: @PengOne: any reasons to bump this question after 7 months?

Comment: @yes123... It was linked from another question I was reading and the bold text bugged me. If my edit had another effect, it was unintended.

Answer (score 2):

```
$score = 0;

foreach ($questions as $question)
{
  if (is_correct($question)) // your handling here
    $score += 5;
  else
    $score -= 3;
}
```