# Score calculation logic

Tags: javascript, math, logic

More complicated than [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395805/logic-for-score-based-on-yes-no-questions-answered-in-a-quiz), I'm after your thoughts on quiz scoring calculation, here's my scenario:

I have X number of options (any HTML element can be supplied as an option), from which a User can pick a combination of options as their answer. So far, I'm trying to keep things generic by:

- maintaining an array of correct answers
- comparing selected answers to the correct answers, by index entries
- incrementing a score by 1 if a correct match is found
- handling radio option question separately, as they're always true/false anyway

Example below: assuming 6 distractor nodes with nodes 0,1,2 being correct if selected. '`selectedAnswers`' is an array containing an index value of any selected distractors. '`correctAnswers`' is a pre-determined set of correct distractor indices.

```
// Each option is worth a standardised amount, unless custom weightings
// are required - not implemented.
var weighting = (100/this.distractors.length);
var score = 0;
for(var i=0;i<this.selectedAnswers.length;i++){
  if( ut.arrayContains(this.correctAnswer, this.selectedAnswers[i]) ){
    // Correct answer found, increase total
    score += weighting*2;
  } else {
    if( yd.hasClass(this.distractors[ this.selectedAnswers[i] ], SELECTED_CLASS) ){
      // Penalise the score by a double weightingfor selecting an incorrect answer
      score -= weighting*2;
      //log('reducing score by 2 weightings');
    } else {
      // Penalise the score by a single weighting for leaving an incorrect node unselected
      score -= weighting;
      //log('reducing score by 1 weighting');
    }
  }
}
this.score( (score<0)? 0 : Math.ceil(score) );
```

It seemed counter-intuitive to decrease the score when an option is unselected, if it would have been incorrect had it been selected - but it seemed to get me closer to the logic I'm after. In fact, the score delivered seems fairly accurate, until you consider the scenario where you're selecting more and more incorrect options and less correct ones.

If I must, I'll carve out a demo from our build and put it live, let me know!

---

EDIT:
Er, sorry I was thinking too hard about this, the question is:

**How do I deliver an accurate % score, taking into consideration both incorrect and correct answers?**

Comment: Eh, the references to 'yd' and 'ut' are convenience shortcuts to YUI.

Comment: Feel free to remove the -1 if this is a viable question now - its a deterrent to actually receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled on this, but I still don't think it covers enough ground:

```
var correctWeighting = 100/this.correctAnswer.length;
var incorrectWeighting = 100/(this.distractors.length-this.correctAnswer.length);
var score = 0;
for(var i=0;i<this.selectedAnswers.length;i++){
    // Scan through all selected distractors and determine if they are in/correct,
    // adjusting the score accordingly
    if( ut.arrayContains(this.correctAnswer, this.selectedAnswers[i]) ){
        score += correctWeighting;
    } else {
        score -= incorrectWeighting;
    }
}

// The score can be calculated to be <0 if there are many incorrect distractors
// selected, which isn't technically wrong (if a bit imprecise?), but a workable
// score should be in the 0-100 range.
this.score( (score<0)? 0 : Math.ceil(score) );
```

It seems to work except, again, when many incorrect answers are selected and few or no correct ones are (the score moves into the negatives). An example of when this might not be good enough is if I have 10 or so options of which say, 3 are correct and I've selected 1 correct (+34%) and more than 3 of them selected but incorrect. It's reasonable in this situation to say that the user deserves at least some credit for their 1 correctly selected answer.

It almost feels like I need to adjust the '`correctWeighting`' depending on some factor revolving around the '`incorrectWeight`'.